# how to exclude a total column using either pg_dump or pg_restore?

Tags: postgresql

We have a table with columns X, Y and Z. We ran pg_dump to get a backup file and now we need to exclude column Y while restoring or if pg_dump itself can exclude column Y, that would help too. I appreciate if someone can give appropriate solution for this!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can use `pg_dump` directly to do that. But you could use it to dump and restore the table as it is and afterwards remove the column with

```
ALTER TABLE .. DROP ..
```